# Перемножение элементов массива javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть массив masA = [13, 12, 10, 15, 55, 66, 12, 13.1, 9, 11] - мне нужно перемножить, каждый элемент массива с двумя последующими, полученный результат проверить на удовлетворение условия (сумма должна быть больше значения переменной srA), если условие удовлетворено умножение прекращается, вывести в консоль элементы массива, которые дали удовлетворяющий результат. В умножении участвует 3 элемента. К примеру 13х12х10 = 1560; затем 12х10х15 = 1800; затем 13х10х15 = 1950 - и так далее, надеюсь суть понятна. Подскажите как мне подобное реализовать?

```
let masA = [13, 12, 10, 15, 55, 66, 12, 13.1, 9, 11];
let srA = 2000;
let perA; // полученный результат с умножения
let elM1; // элемент массива 1
let elM2; // элемент массива 2
let elM3; // элемент массива 3
let allElM = 'Элементы:' + elM1 + ',' + elM2 + ',' + elM3 + ';Результат:' + perA; // элементы результата

if (perA > srA) {
console.log ("найден результат, который больше 2000");
console.log (allElM);
} else {
console.log ("результат, который был бы больше 2000 - не найден");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С возможностью обрывать проход по массиву при нахождении:

```js
const array  = [13, 12, 10, 15, 55, 66, 12, 13.1, 9, 11];
const minProduct = 2000;

let found = null;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
  const product = array[i] * array[i + 1] * array[i + 2];
  if (product > minProduct) {
    found = `Элементы: ${array[i]}, ${array[i + 1]}, ${array[i + 2]}; Результат: ${product}`;
    break;
  }
}

if (found) {
  console.log(`Найден результат, который больше ${minProduct}.`);
  console.log(found);
} else {
  console.log(`Результат, который был бы больше ${minProduct}, не найден.`);
}
```

Comment: Неплохо! Благодарю, а если мне нужно продолжить проход? Т.е. я вижу результат на экране, кликаю на кнопку "продолжить", чтобы найти следующий возможный результат, если его нет выдать в консоль сообщение, если есть соответственно вывести его на экран на замену старому, с возможностью продолжения.
Т.е. цикл останавливается и продолжается каждый раз когда происходит клик кнопке.

⠀let rezult = document.querySelector('.rezult');⠀
rezult.textContent = found;⠀
let buttonContin = document.querySelector('.buttonContin');⠀

Comment: @EVG_JS Думаю, стоит задать это отдельным вопросом, это другой уровень сложности.

Answer (score 1):

Как понял вопрос, примерно так:

```js
let masA = [13, 12, 10, 15, 55, 66, 12, 13.1, 9, 11];
let srA = 2000;



masA.forEach( (i,idx) => {
  if (idx + 3 >= masA.length) return;
  perA = i * masA[idx + 1] * masA[idx + 2]
  answer = perA > srA ? "найден результат, который больше 2000" 
                      : "результат, который был бы больше 2000 - не найден";
  console.log(`${answer} : ${perA}`)
})
```